# How to simulate for multiple regression analysis data with a dummy variable

Tags: r, regression, simulation

I would like to simulate data for a regression analysis, which involves a dummary variable.  While a regression recovers the slopes, it does not recover the intercept:

```
beta <- c(2,3,4)
x1   <- rnorm(100,50,5)
x2   <- sample(c(0,1), replace=T,100)
eps  <- rnorm(100, 0, 5)

y <- beta[1] + beta[2]*x1 + beta[3]*x2 + eps

summary(lm(y~x1 + x2))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-12.6598  -2.7433  -0.2873   2.4616  13.2250 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -8.2858     5.3470  -1.550    0.124    
x1            3.2216     0.1070  30.109  < 2e-16 ***
x2            3.9209     0.9065   4.325  3.7e-05 ***
```

I know the dummy variable shifts the intercept up or down, but I'm confused about what adjustments to make to create a data set that can recover the intercept.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should expect that *on average*, you will recover the true coefficient values. But on a given simulated dataset, your coefficient estimates will deviate. I repeat your simulation setup 1000 times and then I take the average of the coefficient estimates.

```
beta <- c(2,3,4)
do_experiment <- function(n = 100, eps.sd = 5) {
  x1   <- rnorm(n, 50, 5)
  x2   <- sample(c(0,1), replace=T, n)
  eps  <- rnorm(n, 0, eps.sd)

  y <- beta[1] + beta[2]*x1 + beta[3]*x2 + eps

  return(coef(lm(y~x1 + x2)))
}

set.seed(1212)
coefEstimates <- replicate(1000, do_experiment(n = 100))
rowMeans(coefEstimates)

(Intercept)          x1          x2 
   1.972531    3.000327    4.010408

apply(coefEstimates, 1, sd)

(Intercept)          x1          x2 
 5.05588111  0.09988136  1.00523822
```

You could decrease the variance of your error term if you want less variability in your intercept estimate from simulation to simulation. As @rookie mentions, you can also increase the sample size.

```
set.seed(1213)
coefEstimates2 <- replicate(1000, do_experiment(n = 100, eps.sd = 1))
rowMeans(coefEstimates2)

(Intercept)          x1          x2 
   2.046227    2.999186    3.996409 

apply(coefEstimates2, 1, sd)

(Intercept)          x1          x2 
  1.0459009   0.0205488   0.1995421
```

Comment: Thank you, I will decrease the variance and increase the number of observations.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its just an issue of the number of data points. The more data the closer you will get to the correct intercept.

```
set.seed(1111)
beta <- c(2,3,4)
x1   <- rnorm(1E6,50,5)
x2   <- sample(c(0,1), replace=T,1E6)
eps  <- rnorm(1E6, 0, 5)

y <- beta[1] + beta[2]*x1 + beta[3]*x2 + eps

summary(lm(y~x1 + x2))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-25.6565  -3.3651  -0.0003   3.3694  25.8225 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.9914611  0.0504585   39.47   <2e-16 ***
x1          3.0003014  0.0009994 3002.14   <2e-16 ***
x2          3.9902120  0.0099931  399.30   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.997 on 999997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9017,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9017 
F-statistic: 4.587e+06 on 2 and 999997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```